# Can I make the color of the matched word more vivid on macOS dark-mode?

Tags: macos, mojave, preferences, color, dictionary

I use a dark mode and so the matched color using Find functionality on the Dictionary app is very unclear.

[image]

I changed the color from *System Preferences | General* but all the colors look useless on the dark mode, since all of them are very sombre grim.

Is there any way to make the color more vivid, or is switching back to non-dark the only option?